# Argument isn't passed (bash)

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm working with shell scripts.

I'm in the *test section*, where if **an argument** is ***passed***:

> ```
> The expression is true if, and only if, the argument is not null
> ```

And here I have implemented the following code:

```
[ -z $num ]; echo $?;
```

Your exit:

```
0
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, `[-z` should be `[ -z`, otherwise you would be getting an error like `[-z: command not found`. I guess that was just a typo in your question.

It sounds like you're quoting the wrong part of the manual, which would apply to tests like this:

```
[ string ]    # which is equivalent to
[ -n string ]
```

Either of which would return *success* (a `0`) for a non-empty string.

With `-z`, you're checking that the length of the string is 0.

However, as always, **be careful** with unquoted variables, since:

```
[ -z $num ]
# expands to
[ -z ]
# which is interpreted in the same way as
[ string ]
```

i.e. your test becomes "is `-z` a non-empty string?", to which the answer is *yes*, so the test returns `0`. If you use quotes around `"$num"` then the test does what you would expect.